# Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker how to bind to dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Can somebody tell me please how to bind [Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) to dynamicaly created elements? For now I have this code

```
$('.js-eonasdan-datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'cs',
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
    stepping: 5,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
});
```

But it seems it does not work after ajax request with new elements. Thx.

Comment: After every AJAX request success add the picker to the new element, it's easier than to every click event.

Comment: Yes you are right, but it is hooked to other library which triggers ajax call, and I dont know how to catch that ajax event.

Comment: Maybe that library provides a success event that could allow you to do it? At least of librarys say if it was success or not.btw which library is it?

Comment: Yes there is a callback to handle ajax complete. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have this code, but it is terrible to add datetimepicker on every click event:

```
$('body').on('click touchend', '.js-eonasdan-datetimepicker', function()
{
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        locale: 'cs',
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
        stepping: 5,
        ignoreReadonly: true,
    }).data("DateTimePicker").show();
});
```